# Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter

Tags: magento2

I have installed magefan community extension with latest version but then after I change that extension version to old one but now when I am trying to open page it is throwing below error. Not sure where it is taking that class as that config class is not exist.

```
Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #11 [ <required> Magefan\Community\Model\Config $config ] of Magefan\Community\Model\AdminNotificationFeed class
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magefan\Community\Model\Config does not exist
```

Please help me for the same.

Comment: Is there any specific requirement of not to use latest version? What is the version of old module in which you are facing this issuer?

Comment: It's 2.0.14 I am using of magefan community extension.

Comment: `Magefan\Community\Model\Config` class is not exists in 2.0.14 of magefan community extension. It might be possible that some other extension from this vendor is requesting this class. Please check.

Comment: @RahulBarot but after disabling Magefan\Community extension error stop showing and its working fine.